# Citing twice the same paper in LaTeX (with Biber)

Tags: biblatex, parentheses

I'm using LaTeX to write my Masters thesis, and I have some issue with the bibliography. I'm using Biber and the style `bath`.

I have a paper (for now, but will probably have more in the same case) that I need to cite in both the Introduction section and the Discussion section.

The problem is, when I use `\parencite`, the paper appears only in the Introduction and I only have "()" in the Discussion. But if I use `\cite` in the Discussion section, then it appears again, but without parentheses (and I want parentheses, hence the usage of `\parencite`).

Can you help me?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = bath, defernumbers = true,  backend = biber, sorting = nyt, minbibnames=1, maxbibnames=99,  maxcitenames = 2]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}


\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{#1\addcomma}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{#1\addcolon\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\defbibenvironment{onlinebib}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}


\providebool{bbx:subentry}

\newbibmacro*{cite:num}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibopenparen}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}%
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\usebibmacro{cite:num}}{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\bibclosebracket}{\bibcloseparen}}


\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2001,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  journal={Journal},
}

@article{buthor2001,
  author = {Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  journal={Journal},
}

@online{tex,
  title={Online},
  url={https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
  urldate={2019-02-06},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum \parencite{author2001}.
Lorem ipsum \parencite{buthor2001}.

\section*{Discussion}
Lorem ipsum \parencite{tex}. Lorem ipsum \parencite{buthor2001}. Lorem ipsum \parencite{author2001}.

\printbibliography[type=article, heading = subbibliography, title={Articles}]
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[env=onlinebib, heading = subbibliography, type=online, title={Online}, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

which should give:

> **Introduction**
>
> Lorem ipsum (Author, 2001). Lorem ipsum (Buthor and Cuthor, 2001).
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Lorem ipsum [1]. Lorem ipsum (Buthor and Cuthor, 2001). Lorem ipsum (Author, 2001).
>
> **Articles**
>
> Author, A., date. Title. *Journal*.
>
> Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C., date. Title. *Journal*.

But gives

> **Introduction**
>
> Lorem ipsum (Author, 2001). Lorem ipsum (Buthor and Cuthor, 2001).
>
> **Discussion**
>
> Lorem ipsum [1]. Lorem ipsum (). Lorem ipsum (Author, 2001).
>
> **Articles**
>
> Author, A., date. Title. *Journal*.
>
> buthor, B. and Cuthor, C., date. Title. *Journal*.

Comment: Hello! I've checked how to produce a MWE and I still had the issue and thought it was because I redefine \parencite for online entries only, since it worked before I add the redefinition. But then I looked for MWEB and put the bibliography infile as recommanded, and the problem disappeared, even with the new definition. But the problem is that I want to use a separate file for bibliography. And I can't produce a MWEB with the problem...

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: While trying to produce the MWE, I found that the problem arose only (both in the MWE and my thesis) when there are several authors in the paper that is cited twice.

Comment: Thank you for the MWE. I'll see to it at once.

Comment: I have edited my post. I hope you can help me now. I should definetely keep the online references separated because it's a requirement for my thesis. Also, I'm using my own class, but the problem is not related to that since it shows up in report too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`biblatex-bath`'s citation style is based on the standard style `authoryear-comp`. That means that all modifications of its citation commands should be based on `authoryear-comp`'s definitions and not `authoryear`'s or another more generic style.

In particular the definition for `\parencite` should look more like

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibopenparen}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\usebibmacro{cite:num}}{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\bibclosebracket}{\bibcloseparen}}
```

because you need to make sure that your citation command applies the housekeeping (`cite:init`) that `authoryear-comp` needs.

You'll find that the bug was quite context-sensitive. If for example you had changed the citation order of `author2001` and `buthor2001` in the first section, the issue would not have surfaced. But you would have seen a different interesting effect if the author of `buthor2001` had been `Author, A.` as well.

The `-comp` styles need to remember the last `labelname` and `year` in order to compress the citation list properly. But `biblatex` does not clear out the remembered last citation properties at the end of a citation. Instead the macros that store those bits of information are reset at the *beginning* of a citation command with `cite:init`. In the MWE there was no call to `cite:init`, so this reset does not happen, which means that all citation commands will behave as if they were in the same parentheses group.

---

I also recommend to move the punctuation for `@online` out of the field formats directly into the driver with `\setunit`. I also strongly recommend you use the `\url` command for URLs to get proper line breaking and links, if you don't like the default typewriter/monospace font you can change that with `\urlstyle{same}`.

```
\documentclass[british, a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style = bath, defernumbers = true,  backend = biber, sorting = nyt, minbibnames=1, maxbibnames=99, maxcitenames = 2]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}


\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{url}{\url{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\renewbibmacro*{isonline}{}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{online}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{url}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{urldate}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\defbibenvironment{onlinebib}
  {\list
     {\printtext[labelnumberwidth]{%
        \printfield{labelprefix}%
        \printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{\labelnumberwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
      \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{\hss##1}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item}

\providebool{bbx:subentry}

\newbibmacro*{cite:num}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}
  {\ifentrytype{online}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibopenparen}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\usebibmacro{cite:num}}{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \ifentrytype{online}{\bibclosebracket}{\bibcloseparen}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2001,
  author  = {Author, A.},
  year    = {2001},
  title   = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
}
@article{buthor2001,
  author  = {Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C.},
  year    = {2001},
  title   = {Title},
  journal = {Journal},
}
@online{tex,
  title   = {Online},
  url     = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/},
  urldate = {2019-02-06},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum \parencite{author2001}.
Lorem ipsum \parencite{buthor2001}.

\section*{Discussion}
Lorem ipsum \parencite{tex}. Lorem ipsum \parencite{buthor2001}. Lorem ipsum \parencite{author2001}.

\printbibliography[type=article, heading = subbibliography, title={Articles}]
\newrefcontext[sorting=none]
\printbibliography[env=onlinebib, heading = subbibliography, type=online, title={Online}, resetnumbers]
\end{document}
```

[image: **Introduction**//Lorem ipsum (Author, 2001). Lorem ipsum (Buthor and Cuthor, 2001).//**Discussion**//Lorem ipsum [1]. Lorem ipsum (Buthor and Cuthor, 2001). Lorem ipsum//(Author, 2001).//**Articles**//Author, A., 2001. Title. Journal.//Buthor, B. and Cuthor, C., 2001. Title. Journal.//**Online**//[1] https://tex.stackexchange.com/: Online, Accessed 6 February 2019.]

Comment: As for your comments regarding URLs, I had initially removed them, not because I don't like the style, but because they had to be the same font as the text, and I was not aware of \urlstyle{same}. Thanks for the advice!